# Extracting a part of an std::initializer_list<T> C++

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a method `bar(...)` that takes an argument of type `std::initializer_list<T>`. That method calls on another method `foo(...)` that also takes an argument of type `std::initializer_list<T>`. `foo` should be called with the same argument as `bar`, but without the first element of the initializer_list.

```
bar(std::initializer_list<int> l)
{
     ...
     auto l = t.begin();
     ++l;
     foo(new std::initializer_list<int>(l, t.end()));
}
```

I tried the code above, but I just realized that `std::initializer_list<T>` can't be constructed from iterators on the beginning and the end of the `initializer_list<T>`, and give the intended result. It parses the iterators as integers.

```
auto t = new std::initializer_list<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto l = t.begin();
++l;
auto k = new std::initializer_list<int>(l, t.end());
```

Which makes my problem wee harder.

Another idea is to convert a `std::initializer_list` to an array, and array back to `std::initializer_list`, but shorter. That seems silly to me. And I am not really sure how to make an `std::initializer_list` during runtime, even with the help of that array.

Comment: Do you need `foo` to function with `std::initializer_list` outside of `bar`? If not, it should just take two iterators instead.

Comment: `new std::initializer_list<int>(...)`? Where did you learn that from?

Comment: @WhiZTiM As I said, that CAN'T be done.

Comment: @Nelfeal foo needs to function with std::initializer_list outside of bar. foo can only be called with initializer_list parameter.

Comment: @Shocky2 Then you need to reconsider your design. Or, if the design of `foo` is out of your control, you need to stop using it and whatever comes with it. I suppose `foo` is actually the constructor for some class, and a class that defines an `std::initializer_list` constructor should define an iterator-pair constructor (or something equivalent). And if `foo` is a free function, it should have an iterator-pair overload anyway.

Answer (score 4):

An initializer list is a simple wrapper for values, declared with list syntax, `{ 1, 2, 3 }`. The usual purpose of it is to be passed to some function, which will process objects from an initializer list in a smarter way.

Initialize list doesn't have modifier methods, or a constructor, which accepts iterators.

The idea of an array is more adequate. Example:

```
void bar( std::vector<int> _a)
{
    for( int x : _a )
        std::cout << x << ' ';
}

void foo( std::initializer_list<int> _a)
{
    bar( {_a.begin() + 1, _a.end()} );
}

int main()
{
    foo( {1, 2, 3} );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand that, but my problem is following: foo has to be called from bar. foo only takes initializer_list as an argument. How to approach solving it?

Comment: I think you can only pass that initialzer list with no modifications. As an idea - second argument of function will mean an offset, that would be added to list's begin iterator.

Answer (score 3):

From [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> Initializer lists may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer and length. Copying a std::initializer_list does not copy the underlying objects.

`std::initializer_list` does not have a copy constructor, but only a default constructor that can be used to construct empty lists. They are meant to be used as a way of specifying read-only lists.

In your example of function `bar`:

```
void bar(std::initializer_list<int> l)
{
     // [...]
     auto it = t.begin();
     ++it;
     foo(/*foo arguments (see below)*/);
}
```

the scope of initializer list `l` goes beyond the execution of `foo`. Therefore, it is totally valid in this case to implement `foo` with a pair of iterators:

```
void foo( InputIt first, InputIt last )
{
    std::for_each( first, last, []( int x ) {
      std::cout << x << ' ';
    });
}
```

The advantage of this is that `bar` can work with any type of container. Most of the time, you just need to know how to iterate it, not how the elements are really stored. Since now it works with iterators, you can make `foo` completely generic:

```
template < typename Container >
void bar( Container c ) {
    auto first = std::next(std::begin(c));
    foo( first, std::end(c) );
}
```

And will work even with C-style arrays when the size is known:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
bar(a);
```